# I had Schengen visa four years ago and it's revoked due to limitation on my visa

Tags: latvia, schengen-visas

I had Schengen visa four years ago through Latvia, and it was revoked due to limitation on my visa, pls can I apply with my new passport as new applicant through another Schengen country.

I would like to know if my previous information won't have any effect on my new application. With another Schengen.

Comment: As I understand the question, in this case the visa simply expired, but that's very hard to tell. **Yes,** the previous application will affect the new one. The officials will see all the old data. If you went to Latvia and left on time, that will be positive. If you went to Latvia and they threw you out, that's very negative.